# find in a text file all rows with a specific value and display them in the datagridview

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

Good day!

There is a .csv text file in the following format:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fred Smith | f.smith | engineer | 21.12.2021 |
| Ben Taylor | b.taylor | programmer | 23.12.2021 |
| Bill Davis | b.davis | programmer | 19.12.2021 |
| Steve Harris | s.harris | engineer | 23.12.2021 |
| Tom Walker | t.walker | engineer | 23.12.2021 |

with the following code I display data from a text file into a DataGridView:

```vb
Dim list() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\UserList.csv", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
For i = 0 To UBound(list)
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    Dim data() As String = Split(list(i), "|")
    For j = 0 To UBound(data) - 1
        DataGridView1.Item(j, i).Value = data(j)
    Next
Next
```

Tell me how you can display in the datagridview from a text file only those employees where a certain date is indicated in the line of the text file?

For instance:
Specified the date - 23.12.2021
In the DataGridView I want the following result to be displayed:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ben Taylor | b.taylor | programmer | 23.12.2021 |
| Steve Harris | s.harris | engineer | 23.12.2021 |
| Tom Walker | t.walker | engineer | 23.12.2021 |

Tell me how you can make such a selection before displaying data from a text file in the DataGridView?
However, do not delete these lines in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

> For j = 0 To UBound(data)-1

loop run before Date of joining column so that data not add to grid so i removed -1.

Actual problem for the new row should specify the row  and column number as below code.

```
Dim list() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\UserList.csv", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
        For i = 0 To UBound(list)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
            Dim data() As String = Split(list(i), "|")
            For j = 0 To UBound(data)
                'DataGridView1.Item(j, i).Value = data(j)
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = data(j)
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways available. If you put the data into something which implements the IBindingListView interface such as a DataTable then you could use the Filter property. Documentation for that: [BindingSource.Filter Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter)

Or, as I show here, you can use a List and use LINQ to create the filter, like this:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim userData As List(Of User) = Nothing
    Dim inputDateFormat As String = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    Dim displayDateFormat As String = "dd.MM.yyyy"

    Public Class User
        Property Name As String
        Property Email As String
        Property Title As String
        Property MagicDate As DateTime

        Sub New(name As String, email As String, title As String, magicDate As DateTime)
            Me.Name = name
            Me.Email = email
            Me.Title = title
            Me.MagicDate = magicDate
        End Sub

    End Class

    Sub LoadData(src As String)
        userData = New List(Of User)
        For Each a In File.ReadLines(src)
            Dim parts = a.Split("|"c)
            If parts.Count = 4 Then
                Dim md = DateTime.ParseExact(parts(3), inputDateFormat, Nothing)
                Dim u = New User(parts(0), parts(1), parts(2), md)
                userData.Add(u)
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Sub ShowData()
        ' show all the data
        ShowData(Nothing)
    End Sub

    Sub ShowData(selectedDate? As DateTime)

        If userData Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim bs As New BindingSource

        If selectedDate.HasValue Then
            ' select only the data with the desired date
            bs.DataSource = userData.Where(Function(u) u.MagicDate = selectedDate.Value)
        Else
            ' show all the data
            bs.DataSource = userData
        End If

        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
        DataGridView1.Columns("MagicDate").DefaultCellStyle.Format = displayDateFormat

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData("C:\temp\UserList.csv")
        ShowData(New Date(2021, 12, 23))

    End Sub

End Class
```

To get:

[image: DataGridView with only rows having the selected date]

Answer (score 0):

```vb
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
       Dim pattern As String = "23.12.2021"
       Dim Path As String = "D:\UserList.csv"
       Dim _row As String
       Dim separator As Char = "|"

       For Each _row In File.ReadAllLines(Path, Encoding.Default)
           If _row.Contains(pattern) Then
               DataGridView1.Rows.Add(_row.Split(separator))
           End If
       Next _row
   End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like:

```
Dim list() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\UserList.csv", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
           Dim ub as Integer
               For i = 0 To UBound(list)
                Dim data() As String = Split(list(i), "|")
               ub = UBound(data)
                If data(ub) = "23.12.2021" Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                  For j = 0 To ub - 1
                    DataGridView1.Item(j, i).Value = data(j)
                  Next
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the "User" class that Andrew Morton created:

```
Dim fileName = "C:\Bin\myFile.csv"


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim filterDate = Date.Parse("23.12.2021")
    SetDataSource(filterDate)
End Sub


Private Sub SetDataSource(dateStamp As Date)
    Dim data = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Skip(1).
                Select(Function(line) line.Split(",")).
                Select(Function(x) New User(x)).
                Where(Function(x) x.MagicDate = dateStamp)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = data.ToList()
End Sub

Public Class User
    Public Sub New(x() As String)
        Name = x.ElementAt(0)
        Email = x.ElementAt(1)
        Title = x.ElementAt(2)
        MagicDate = x.ElementAt(3)
    End Sub

    Property Name As String
    Property Email As String
    Property Title As String
    Property MagicDate As DateTime

End Class
```

[image]

I added the Skip(1) in the LINQ so it ignores the header row. This can be removed if no header is present.